# Where does the compiling and linking of a bash configure script happens?

Tags: windows, bash, makefile, autoconf

When compiling a project that comes with bash configure scripts such as: autogen.sh, makefile.am, configure.ac, configure.in etc. Where does compiling takes place, if you invoke these commands:

```
autogen.sh 
autoconf configure.ac
...
...
./configure
make
make install
```

Does the compiling happens before the "make install"? or at "make install". I am only interested
in compiling the library so that my code can compile rather than to actually install the software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, `configure` prepares the Makefiles, `make` compiles everything and `make install` copies the binaries into the appropriate folders on your system.

Comment: Okay, so if the copies are on the build folder, can you run your code with the copies(build) and this is the folder where your compiler will find the .h and .cpp files it needs to compile your written code?

Comment: I did not quite get that question. After the `make` step, the compiled files are usually residing in a folder below the folder you called the `configure` script in and depending on the package you are compiling they could be usable. But instead of doing this you could usually pass a custom --prefix to the configure script, that tells `make install` to install to a different (eg. empty) location, so you know what was compiled and can remove it easily.

Comment: to clarify, do you need to run configure again. If you decide to write your own code that calls or uses this sources code?